# JS error on Chrome (with Device Toolbar enable)

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I turn on the `tablet` mode or the `phone` mode in Chrome, I get a javascript error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'elementFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
    at HTMLHtmlElement.avp.disableTouchSafari (viewer3D.min.js:18)`

I've just update Chrome to the last version.

Any idea?

Comment: May I know what the Viewer version you're using?

Comment: The version v2.  You have the link in my previous email if you want to test.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t aware of that. I will test it while backing to work. Have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might an issue of Forge Viewer. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused.

I have logged a request **LMV-3401** `[Autodesk.Viewing.Private.disableTouchSafari() reports error while viewing model with Chrome DevTools' Device Mode in macOS]` to our development team to allocate time to investigate. As it requires further exploration and possibly a modification to our Viewer, please make a note of this number for future reference.

You are welcome to request an update on the status of this request or to provide additional information on it at any time quoting this request number via `forge.help@autodesk.com`.

However, I think this error didn't affect main features of Viewer. At the meanwhile, I think a real mobile device will help you in this case since this error didn't show up while testing on my Ipad.

Cheers,