# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'elementFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: mobile, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The uncaught type error as shown in title keeps getting thrown on mobile simulation. I don't know if it affects anything yet. however, since there's no place or contact email for me to submit bug for autodesk forge, I'm just gonna write it here. Why does this only happen in mobile and not on desktop?

Browser: Chrome Mobile (Ipad pro 5s simulation)
Original File Type: .rvt, .nwd
Converted File Type: .svf
Action that causes that exception: Touch, touch-drag, touch-release

[image: Uncaught Type errors in mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a known issue reported as LMV-3401, see here for some detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50791919/7745569

However, the patch of this issue has been released with the last Viewer (from v6.x), please have a try!

Comment: tested the new version, new version no longer report that error on click, thanks!